# How to prevent user from going back to previous page after logout in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I am working on polymer app where the landing page itself is the sign-in page and after the user logs out successfully i am redirecting him to sign-in page like this

```
   window.history.pushState({}, null, '/');
   window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'));
```

now if the user clicks browser back button he will be taken to previous Url.How do I prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to change the `history` object of `window`. But, here are some crazy ideas you can try:

- You can overwrite `history.back()` and make it null if user is logged out.
- You can have a check each time a page changes for if user is logged in, if not then you can use `location.replace("you home page")` to take him back to home page.
- After logout you can remove all the child elements from iron-pages except for your home page and then add them again when user logs in(or refresh the page).